Infinite Start/Stop simulation
I've just instaled gazebo harmonic following this link: https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/install_ubuntu
I did gz sim and choose and empty world
However there is a problem, the simulation starts/stops automatically infinitly
How to stop this?
If more information is needed let me know
Best Regards,
Ricardo Gonçalves
Edit:
I reinstalled gazebo harmonic now I can't even do gz sim this is the return:
The 'gz' command provides a command line interface to the Gazebo Tools.
gz  [options]
List of available commands:
help:          Print this help text.
log:           Record or playback topics.
msg:           Print information about messages.
param:         List, get or set parameters.
service:       Print information about services.
topic:         Print information about topics.
Options:
--force-version   Use a specific library version.
--versions                 Show the available versions.
--commands                 Show the available commands.
Use 'gz help ' to print help for a command.
it doesn't start a new world
